# Area of circle showing concavity

Tags: multivariable-calculus

How to find the area of circle showing the change of concavities of function $$\displaystyle f(x,y)=1-e^{-(x^2+y^2)/2}$$

Comment: Which circle? What radio is it?

Comment: the circle is inside the graph of the function

Answer (score 1):

The red circle shows where the curvature on the function changes sign.  (Perhaps this is what the OP seeks... hard to know.)

[image]

Here's a cross section (in blue) and the second derivative (in tan), which changes sign at radius = 1.

[image]

Comment: so it is impossible to find the area of circle?

Comment: Let me guess his circle is the boundary of the  set of $(x,y)$ values for which the Hessian matrix is negative definite.  And that his textbook or notebook has a non-standard definition  of  concavity.

Comment: that's right except I haven't learned about Hessian matrix so is there any way to find the that circle without using Hessian matrix?

Comment: @kimchilover:  Given the level of sophistication of the OP (his reputation is $6$), I strongly doubt he's working with Hessians.

Comment: @AndyLam, maybe you should spell out exactly what "concavities of a function" means in your textbook or course?  I think there is a terminology mismatch going on.  To me, a function is concave on all of its range at once, or not; I'm afraid to you a function can be concave at particular points and not others.  What is your official precise definition of "concave"?